# how can i check multiple (&&) in PHP if...else Statements

Tags: php

how can i check multiple (&&) in if else Statements

```
if (!$lock1 && !$lock2 && !$lock3 && !$lock4 && !$lock5 && !$lock6 && !$lock7 && !$lock8)
        {
            echo "ok";
        }else{
            echo 1;
        }
```

note : the all variable just true or false

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote?

Comment: My thoughts too..

Comment: Your code will echo `OK` when none of the variables are true. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter for this.

```
$arr = [$lock1,$lock2,$lock3,$lock4,$lock5,$lock6,$lock7,$lock8];

if(count(array_filter($arr)) === 0){
  echo " all false ";
}else{
  echo "all not false";
}
```

Comment: Of course, you should be starting with an array `$lock = [...]` in the first place then…

Comment: @deceze Yes that's the correct approach instead of creating 8 different ones. I just went with what OP had in place.